# Identify full vs half yearly datasets in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with two fields of interest for this particular exercise: a CHAR(3) ID and a DATETIME.  The ID identifies the submitter of the data - several thousand rows.  The DATETIME is not necessarily unique, either.  (The primary keys are other fields of the table.)

Data for this table is submitted every six months.  In December, we receive July-December data from each submitter, and in June we receive July-June data.  My task is to write a script that identifies people who have only submitted half their data, or only submitted January-June data in June.

...Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later realised that I was supposed to check to make sure that there was data for *both* July to December and January to June.  So this is what I wound up in v2:

```
SELECT  @avgmonths = AVG(x.[count])
FROM    ( SELECT    CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT DATEPART(month,
                                                 DATEADD(month,
                                                         DATEDIFF(month, 0, dscdate),
                                                         0))) AS FLOAT) AS [count]
          FROM      HospDscDate
          GROUP BY  hosp
         ) x

IF @avgmonths > 7 
    SET @months = 12
ELSE 
    SET @months = 6


SELECT  'Submitter missing data for some months' AS [WarningType],
     t.id
FROM    TheTable t
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM   TheTable t1
                 WHERE  t.id = t1.id
                 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATEPART(month,
                       DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, t1.Date), 0))) < @months )
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I wouldn't worry about the efficiency of the query since apparently it only needs to run twice a year!

There are a few ways to do this, which one is 'best' depends on the data that you have. The datediff (on max/min date values) you suggested should work, another option is to just count records for each submitted within each date range, e.g.

```
select * from (
    select T.submitterId,
        (select count(*) 
        from TABLE T1
        where T1.datefield between [july] and [december]
        and T1.submitterId = T.submitterId
        group by T1.submitterId) as JDCount,
        (select count(*)
        from TABLE T2
        where T2.datefield between [december] and [june]
        and T2.submitterId = T.submitterId
        group by T2.submitterId) as DJCount
    from TABLE T) X
where X.JDCount <= 0 OR X.DJCount <= 0
```

Caveat: untested query off the top of my head; your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

For interest, this is what I wound up using.  It was based off Stephen's answer, but with a few adaptations.

It's part of a larger script that's run every six months, but we're only checking this every twelve months - hence the "If FullYear = 1".  I'm sure there's a more stylish way to identify the boundary dates, but this seems to work.

```
IF @FullYear = 1 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @FirstDate AS DATETIME
        DECLARE @LastDayFirstYear AS DATETIME
        DECLARE @SecondYear AS INT
        DECLARE @NewYearsDay AS DATETIME
        DECLARE @LastDate AS DATETIME

        SELECT @FirstDate = MIN(dscdate), @LastDate = MAX(dscdate)
        FROM    TheTable
      
        SELECT  @SecondYear = DATEPART(yyyy, @FirstDate) + 1
        SELECT  @NewYearsDay = CAST(CAST(@SecondYear AS VARCHAR) 
            + '-01-01' AS DATETIME)

        INSERT  INTO @AuditResults
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    'Submitter missing Jan-Jun data', t.id
                FROM    TheTable t
                WHERE   
                    EXISTS ( 
                        SELECT 1
                        FROM   TheTable t1
                        WHERE  t.id = t1.id 
                            AND t1.date >= @FirstDate
                            AND t1.date < @NewYearsDay )
                    AND NOT EXISTS ( 
                        SELECT 1
                        FROM   TheTable t2
                        WHERE  t2.date >= @NewYearsDay
                        AND t2.date <= @LastDate
                        AND t2.id = t.id
                        GROUP BY t2.id )
                GROUP BY t.id
    END
```